# Check if int array contains a value, if so, how many

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I have this integer array:

```
int[] responses = new int[3];
```

The script then pings an IP address 4 times.  If it gets a reply, it adds a "1" to the array.  If it does not get a reply, it adds a "0" to the array.  I would like to see if the array contains any zeros, and if so, how many.  Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: That's pretty trivial, what have you tried?

Comment: On a side note, why reserve space for three elements if you want to store four? The suggestions to use a list is also good.

Comment: @Romiox whoops, good point.  I am sort of new to c# and I thought 0 was an element.

Comment: @Matt It is! But `int[3]` gives you three places to store an element, indexed 0, 1, and 2. Index 3 is 'out of bounds'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int failedResponsesCount = responses.Count(r => r == 0);
```

I also suggest to use `List<bool>` to keep history of responses. Because you are adding items to it (btw, with array you can't tell whether `0` was 'added' or it just default value of item). Also you have pretty boolean logic here (you either get reply or not) - you don't need to use integers for representing response type.

Answer (score 0):

Another way ;)

```
int total = responses.Count(x => x == 0);
if(total > 0)
    //Do something;
else
    //Do something else
```

Comment: How is this better than just running `Count` directly and then checking the result? Now you have to iterate the list more than once.

Comment: You´re right! I only did it because he asked for that. 
" I would like to see if the array contains any zeros, and if so, how many. " But as you said, is nt efficient, let me edit

Comment: Your latest edit doesn't satisfy the 'how many' requirement ;) You could go for `int count; if (count = responses.Count(x => x == 0) > 0)`.

Comment: +1 for you Romiox! Thanks for info! Edited!